# How many client devices can communicate to a single USB Bluetooth Dongle?

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth, communication, simultaneous

I'm planning on writing a debug app (for my Android device) that can send data back to my PC via Bluetooth.

Can a single Bluetooth dongle on my PC connect to multiple Android devices simultaneously, or do I need one dongle per connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This belongs to the [Android Stackexchage](http://android.stackexchange.com). Anyways you can pair with multiple BT devices with most dongles.

Comment: Given that the goal is development, and that its much more a bluetooth (and PC-side) question than an android one, it probably does not belong on android stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe, but  if you strip out the goal from this question, you will see that, this is a problem that even a non-programmer can face :)

Comment: a non-programmer is likely to be facing the limitations of the already written program they have chosen before the limitations of the hardware.  Since the question isn't if the android bluetooth implementation can connect with multiple pc's, but if the pc one can connect with multiple devices, it's really about the pc bluetooth capability, not the android one, and thus benefits from the larger base of relevant expertise here.

Comment: Thanks, honestly I spent a couple of minutes debating where to post it, but decided that this question was really independent of the Android, and was more on the PC / Bluetooth dongle end...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 7 simultaneous connections from the PC dongle